# Does 60 fps w/ vertical sync enabled imply 60hz monitor?

Tags: display, gpu, fps

I get a flat 60 FPS with my new supposed 144Hz monitor with vertical sync enabled.

Shouldn't I get 144 FPS if the monitor is 144Hz? With vsync off the GPU is pushing out 200+ fps.

I don't care about having vsync on. I'm just afraid that for some reason my monitor isn't actually doing 144Hz.

Comment: Have you set your OS display settings to 144Hz?

Comment: fps & monitor sync are completely unrelated. What your GPU is putting out & how your screen is drawing it have no correlation whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this and it was 60Hz with no option to change. Which led me to try DVI.

Comment: My Asus 144Hz monitor only support 144hz over DVI-D!

Comment: If your Monitor /desktop is set for 60hz it will not display 144 fps.  Your video card maybe 200 fps, but everything above 60 is being ignored by your monitor at 60hz

Comment: Yes cybernard that is the point of the question... I bought a 144 Hz monitor and was seeing symptoms of a 60 Hz rate, and wanted to know what to do. Using DVI was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hertz (Hz) and frames-per-second (FPS) are two independent factors.

For your monitor, hertz is the number of times your monitor can redraw the image on the screen.  The higher the hertz, the smoother the movement on screen is.  This value is based on the hardware in your monitor.

FPS is the number of your times your graphics card can build the image your monitor is trying to draw on the screen.  That image is called a frame.  The number of FPS is not set in stone.  It is based on your graphics card - really your whole computer - and the software generating the graphics.  Just because you see your FPS hit 200 FPS, that doesnt mean it can stay that high.  In intense 3D scenes, the FPS might drop to keep the game fluid, at the cost of detail.

Now, if your FPS is high enough, it can be draw frames multiple times faster than your monitor can draw them to the screen.  This can cause a problem called screen tearing.  Screen tearing is when your graphics card is building a new frame and your monitor displays the frame during that update.  This can make part of the image on a screen look like someone sliced the image on screen in half and shifted one half over a little.  Many people find this very visually disruptive.

Vertical Synchronization (vsync) attempts to solve the problem of screen tearing by reducing your monitors Hz and your graphics cards FPS to multiples of each other.  This reduces or eliminates screen tearing at the cost of performance.  There is no need for vsync if you do not notice screen tearing.

People often see the checkboxes for things that improve visual effects, like anti-aliasing and other visual effects.  Naturally, people want to turn those on, even at the cost of performance.  Vsync is often listed with those options and people check it without knowing what it does.  Then they wonder why they are only getting 60 FPS in a game, knowing that they have seen other games go much higher.